# c# библиотеки для работы с прокси

Tags: c#, namespace, library

Ребят помогите найти библиотеку, 2 дня ищу без толку

```
IProxyClient proxy = factory.CreateProxy ( ProxyType.Socks4, item.Key, item.Value );
```

Подчеркивается ProxyType.Socks4,так как этот фрагмент взял из гугла, не знаю откуда его импортировать.
Заранее признателен за ответы и уделенное время.

Comment: [Первая ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231890/mail-dll-through-proxy-c-sharp) из гугла, запрос - `IProxyClient proxy = factory.CreateProxy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этой задачи нужно скачать библиотеки mail.dll и proxy.dll с [сайта разработчика](https://limilabs.com/mail/download).
В архиве будут находиться нужные библиотеки.

Comment: Пробовал, там нет этого enum'a, вот здесь (https://www.limilabs.com/blog/tag/http-proxy) написано что нужно подключить еще дополнительно proxy.dll чтоб работало, но его в NuGet'e нет и в гугле тоже не нашел

Comment: что хотите реализовать? с чем должен взаимодействовать ваш код?

Comment: Подключение к почте по протоколу IMAP с SSL через прокси

Comment: скачайте библиотеку proxy с сайта https://www.limilabs.com/mail/download, там будет и mail.dll и proxy.dll

Comment: Благодарю, нашел